# Drupal Form API - Display Form Values upon submission

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-6

I've read the Drupal API Form documentation but there's something I'm just not getting.
 It's probably really simple but I can't find out how to display the submitted values of a form after it's submission.

*edited code

```
<?php

function createForm_enigmaFilters($form_state) {
    $form = array();

    $form['#submit'][] = 'createForm_enigmaFilters_submit';

    $form['list'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup', 
        '#prefix' => '<ul id="enigmaFilters">',
        '#suffix' => '</ul>',
    );

    $form['list']['startDate'] = array(
        '#id' => 'txtStartDate',   
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '20',
        '#title' => 'Date de début',
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>',
    );

    $form['list']['endDate'] = array(
        '#id' => 'txtEndDate', 
        '#weight' => '1',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '20',
        '#title' => 'Date de fin',
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>',
    );

    $form['list']['enigmaName'] = array(
        '#id' => 'txtEnigmaTitle',
        '#weight' => '2',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '100',
        '#title' => 'Nom des énigmes',
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>',
    );

    $form['list']['lstAnswers'] = array(
        '#id' => 'lstAnswers',
        '#weight' => '3',
        '#default_value' => 'Uniquement les bonnes',
        '#key_type' => 'associative',
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            'Toutes les réponses' => 'Toutes les réponses',
            'Uniquement les bonnes' => 'Uniquement les bonnes',
        ),
        '#multiple_toggle' => '1',
        '#title' => 'Réponses',
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>',
    );

    $form['list']['promotionYear'] = array(
        '#id' => 'txtPromotionYear',
        '#weight' => '4',
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '40',
        '#title' => 'Année de promotion',
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>',
    );

    $form['list']['submit'] = array(
        '#id' => 'lnkApplyFilters',
        '#weight' => '5',
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Rechercher'),
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>',
    );

    return $form;
}

function createForm_enigmaFilters_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    echo $form_state['values']['startDate'];
    echo $form_state['values']['endDate'];
    echo $form_state['values']['enigmaName'];
    echo $form_state['values']['lstAnswers'];
    echo $form_state['values']['promotionYear'];
}

echo drupal_get_form('createForm_enigmaFilters');

?>
```

Comment: what is your output? try using print_r( $myform ) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you won't see the output of this (though it will exist briefly) because the form will redirect to the same page after calling the submit handler - if it didn't you would see the form twice because you print the form in the submit handler as well as wherever you print it in the first place!

I suggest you loose the

```
echo drupal_get_form('createForm_enigmaFilters');
```

And swap your other calls to echo to [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6), like:

```
drupal_set_message('start date: '.$form_state['values']['startDate']);
```

This will mean that your message will be shown next time a page is actually shown - ie after the submit hook has been called.

let me know if this is confusing/doesn't work :)

Comment: drupal_set_message works great, thanks! However I don't think I could use it in my context though. 

I wanted to use the form's inputs as filters for a dynamic SQL query. This way, in the submit callback function, I would call my custom BuildAndDisplay(startdate, endate, etc.) function with the submitted values as params, and display the query results on the reload. Have an idea how I could do that? Thanks a ton for the help by the way, really appreciate!

Comment: Okay the drupal_set_message was just for displaying the values so you could see they were being submitted correctly. In order to make a page displaying your results you would usually want to re-direct to another page which would have your query and the code to build the display. so you could put something like drupal_goto('mypage/'.$form_state['values']['startDate']...). Have a google. Though it does sound like views may be the way forward for you now I know a little more.

Comment: cool I'm gonna try this. Everyone tells me that Views would've been the way to go, and I know it, but I'm so beginner that I wasn't able to create a view returning the same thing as my complex SQL Query. But that's another story I guess. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

drupal_get_form should call createMyForm.

For createMyForm_submit to work, you need to do

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'createMyForm_submit';
```

In your form. This adds a callback to the form.

But you should also be adhering to drupal coding practices, to maximize your efficiency with the API.

Comment: The 'createMyForm' call was a typo, sorry about that. I updated my code with the submit callback, but the values still aren't showing after submission.

Answer (score -1):

What I did is just use arg(x) where x is whatever the folder number in sequence is. This may not always be ideal though.